# Date Range in Reporting services 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created one report where i want to pull the records from specified date range

I have two parameters i.e. StartDate and EndDate. Both are date/time data type.

What I want to do is set the default date for the StartDate parameter as +7 days from today's date, and have the EndDate as +7 days from the StartDate?

Basically the reports need to show everything for the following week

E.g. If the report is created today (Monday 22nd Sept); it would show data between Monday 29th to Sunday 5th.

Please let me know how I would specify this as an expression under the parameters, or could this be done within the DataSet?

Comment: Have you looked at using the `DateAdd()` and `Today()` expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the StartDate Parameter's default value as **=now.AddDays(7)**
And EndDate Parameter's default value **=Cdate(Parameters!StartDate.value).AddDays(7)**